# SQL Query with union and join

Tags: mysql, union

my set-up is like this

```
Table1: company_group - company_id, company_name
Table2: store         - store_id, store_name
Table3: sales         - sales_id, company_id, store_id, date, sales
Table4: wh_sales      - wh_sale_id, company_id, store_id, date, sales

Table5: purchase      - purchase_id, company_id, store_id, date, purchase
```

Now I am able to get the data for the first four tables using the select and union query, but I can't make out how and which join I should use to get the data for the table5 in the same table

I am using the query for the first four tables like

```
select `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`sales`.`sales` 
from company_group, store,sales
where `company_group`.`company.id`=`sales`.`company.id`
and `store`.`store.id`=`sales`.`store.id`
group by company_name,store_name, 'MONTH'

UNION

select `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`wh_sales`.`sales`
from company_group, store,wh_sales
where `company_group`.`company.id`=`wh_sales`.`company.id`
and `store`.`store.id`=`wh_sales`.`store.id`
group by company_name,store_name, 'MONTH'
```

now how can I include the Table5 so that I can get the result like

```
company_name store_name   month      sales    purchase
company-a     store-c    December    40000    45000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
select `company_name, `store_name`, MONTH, sum(`sales`) as sales, sum(purchase) as purchase   from (
select `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`sales`.`sales` , 0 as purchase
from company_group, store,sales
where `company_group`.`company.id`=`sales`.`company.id`
and `store`.`store.id`=`sales`.`store.id`

UNION

select `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`wh_sales`.`sales`, 0 as purchase
from company_group, store,wh_sales
where `company_group`.`company.id`=`wh_sales`.`company.id`
and `store`.`store.id`=`wh_sales`.`store.id`

UNION

select `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH, 0 as sales, purchase
from company_group, store,purchase
where `company_group`.`company.id`=`purchase`.`company.id`
and `store`.`store.id`=`purchase`.`store.id`) a
group by company_name,store_name, 'MONTH'
```

The group by clause is not needed for the inner queries since there is no group function. I have moved it to the outermost query

Comment: I am not getting the result as expected.

Comment: With your query I am getting the results with some modification to the query like adding the group by in all the select inside paranthesis. The problem is I am getting the same result two times and purchase figure not showing against the sales figure, but creates its own separate row, whereas I want that for say december I should get all the figures for a particular store in one row.

Comment: I think the problem is with the group by clause at the end of this query, it has the word 'MONTH' which should be just MONTH (without quotes). Moreover you shouldn't need the group by clauses with the individual subqueries. Fix the quotes issue and remove the group by clauses inside the subquery and try again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.`company_name`, t1.`store_name`,t1.`MONTH`,t1.`sales`, `purchase`.`purchase` FROM (

select `company_group`.`company_id`, `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`sales`.`sales` 
    from company_group, store,sales
    where `company_group`.`company.id`=`sales`.`company.id`
    and `store`.`store.id`=`sales`.`store.id`
    group by company_name,store_name, 'MONTH'

UNION

select `company_group`.`company_id`,`company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`wh_sales`.`sales`
    from company_group, store,wh_sales
    where `company_group`.`company.id`=`wh_sales`.`company.id`
    and `store`.`store.id`=`wh_sales`.`store.id`
    group by company_name,store_name, 'MONTH') AS t1 

LEFT JOIN `purchase` 
ON t1.`company_id`=`purchase`.`company_id` 
AND t1.`store_id`=`purchase`.`store_id`
```

Not sure if this is valid syntax specifically for MySQL, but you should get the idea anyway.

**UPD:** Rewritten the query fixing errors mentioned in comments

Comment: `t1.*` means 'all the fields from table t1'. In turn, t1 is a table alias for all the data selected by `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` query inside brackets.

Comment: I am missing something somewhere. In the first line, does purchase refers to purchase field from table purchase or purchase table itself? and left join `purchase` refers to purchase field or purchase table? also I am getting an error Unknown column 't1.company_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Should be working now... As for your questions, in the first line I meant _field_ `purchase` from table `purchase` - changed this to be obvious. `left join purchase` refers to table - there's no such thing as joining field with something.

Answer (score 0):

Sales vs whole & sales, displaying the purchase price for both right ?
Try this one.

```
select `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`sales`.`sales`, `purchase`.`purchase`
from company_group, store,sales, purchase
where `company_group`.`company.id`=`sales`.`company.id`
and `store`.`store.id`=`sales`.`store.id`
group by company_name,store_name, 'MONTH'

UNION

select `company_group`.`company_name, `store`.`store_name`, MONTHNAME(date) AS MONTH,`wh_sales`.`sales`, `purchase`.`purchase`
from company_group, store,wh_sales, purchase
where `company_group`.`company.id`=`wh_sales`.`company.id`
and `store`.`store.id`=`wh_sales`.`store.id`
group by company_name,store_name, 'MONTH'
```

Adding  `purchase`.`purchase` to the `SELECT` clause and the `purchase` TABLE to the `FROM` clause provides access to the table's `purchase` price field. Which, according to your projected table's `purchase` column is essential **AND** the simplest method.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem in question, we can improve this answer's quality by explaining *why* the code works.